# Sound flower not picking up screen sound

Tags: macos, audio, audio-recording, quicktime, desktop-recording

I have a problem that is really puzzling me. I own an old macbook pro 2008 and I just have upgraded to a more recent macbook pro.
One of the things I need to do is screen recording, both sound and video. I have on my old macbook, set up a multi-output device and I got sound flower so that I can use quicktime to do screen recording whilst at the same time watch and hear what I am doing. I have done this in the past without any problems. On my new macbook, I have set up everything exactly the same, yet no sound is recorded. This is driving me crazy. I need to be able to do this for work, so until I can sort this problem, my new macbook is useless. Has anyone encountered this problem? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and answer my own question in case it may help someone in the future. There was nothing wrong with my settings or soundflower. I updated the system to Sierra and it worked without a problem. So 100% their end kind of problem.